# Freemarker datetime for different locales

Tags: datetime, locale, freemarker

I have following code,

```
<#assign dateAndtime = "2020-08-17T16:08:31.496Z"?datetime.iso?string("yyyy年MM月dd日（E） HH:mm")>  
${dateAndtime}
```

output is `2020年08月17日（Mon） 21:38`

I want to print like `"2020year08month17day (Mon) 21:38"`. What should i pass instead of `"yyyy年MM月dd日（E） HH:mm"`

I can get the year, month and date separetely and then append with "year","month"and "day" strings respectively to get like `2020year08month17day (Mon) 21:38"`. But i dont want to do that. Is there any other way to acheive this?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<#assign dateAndtime = "2020-08-17T16:08:31.496Z"?datetime.iso?string["yyyy'year'MM'month'dd'day'（E） HH:mm"]>
${dateAndtime}
```

The date format used is the one from java's [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).